# Debugging issue moving value into SP register

Tags: gdb, qemu, arm64, osdev

I am programming a hobby OS in ARM (targeting Raspberry Pi 3b+) under the AArch64 model.

Early during the boot process, we are setting up the stack pointer in preparation of jumping to our `kernel_main` function. The execution seems to go *fine* but when debugging with GDB under QEMU, the debugger skips a whole bunch of assembly code as soon as I load an address into the `sp` register.

I can see that the code that was skipped was successfully executed, the issue is just that the debugger is skipping it and it's driving me crazy since I need to debug some stuff in the area.

Sample code here, the debugger goes line by line until the `set_stack` label's second instruction. As soon as the `mov sp, x1` is executed the debugger skips through to the `kernel_main` function, on which I have a breakpoint.

```
_start:
    // read cpu id, stop slave cores
    mrs     x1, mpidr_el1
    and     x1, x1, #3
    cbz     x1, 2f
    // cpu id > 0, stop
1:  wfe
    b       1b
2:  // cpu id == 0

set_stack:
    // set top of stack just before our code (stack grows to a lower address per AAPCS64)
    ldr     x1, =_start    // _start is set at address 0x80000 by the linker
    mov     sp, x1    // <-- Problematic code here. This loads address 0x80000 into SP

    // clear bss
    ldr     x1, =__bss_start
    ldr     w2, =__bss_size
3:  cbz     w2, 4f
    str     xzr, [x1], #8
    sub     w2, w2, #1
    cbnz    w2, 3b

    // jump to C code, should not return
4:  bl      kernel_main
    // for failsafe, halt this core too
    b       1b
```

```c
kernel_main(uint64_t dtb_ptr32, uint64_t x1, uint64_t x2, uint64_t x3)
{
    uart_init(3);
    uart_puts("Hello, kernel World!\r\n");

    while (1)
        uart_putc(uart_getc());
}
```

Code is loosely taken from https://github.com/bztsrc/raspi3-tutorial.

What's interesting is that, if I do this GDB command `set $sp=0x80000` to write the same address into the SP register, the `mov sp` instruction will be stepped through correctly by GDB and I can continue on the following instructions as expected.

Setup:

- Source code: https://github.com/tristanred/ArmOS/tree/feature/memory-management-basic
- Compiler:

  - GCC (cross compiler) based on gcc version 12.2.0. `aarch64-elf-gcc`
  - Assembler (cross compiler) based on GNU assembler (GNU Binutils) 2.39, `aarch64-elf-as`
- qemu-system-aarch64: QEMU emulator version 6.2.0

  - Launch command is: `qemu-system-aarch64 -M raspi3b -kernel $(OUTDIR)myos.img -nographic -s -S -d int`
- GDB-Multiarch 12.1
- Execution state: 64-bit (AArch64)

My current workaround is to have a label right after the instruction and have it trigger a breakpoint.

Would still like to know if anyone have had a similar experience or might know what is happening ? Maybe a bug on QEMU or GDB ?

Comment: My gut feeling would be that `x1` is indeed not `0x80000` but some other value which is not aligned to 16 bytes, causing an sp alignment fault.

Comment: Are you using `step` or `stepi` to move forward through the assembly code?  My guess is you are using `step` and the weird behaviour you are seeing relates to GDB's frame tracking in some way, though I can't think what the problem is exactly off the top of my head.  Switch to using `stepi` and see if that gives the behaviour you want.

Comment: You should tell us what your QEMU command line is.

Comment: SP alignment is probably not the issue -- architecturally those faults happen only when a misaligned SP is used for a load or store; and in any case QEMU doesn't currently emulate them.

Comment: QEMU command is `qemu-system-aarch64 -M raspi3b -kernel $(OUTDIR)myos.img -nographic -s -S -d int`

Comment: @Andrew I am using the `s` (step) command. I'll try with `stepi`, I think I was mixing `s` vs `n`. Will try just doing `stepi` in a short while.

Comment: Interesting, I am now using `stepi` and it's going through properly. Not skipping forward to next breakpoint. I'll try a few other things to make sure it's correct but feel free to create an answer and I'll approve it if it ends up being the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `step` or `next` to move through this assembler code then you should consider using `stepi` or `nexti` instead.

The `step` and `next` commands try to be "smarter" about how they operate, they make use of the debug information line table to ensure that GDB step by complete source lines.  These commands also track which frame the command starts in, and use this to try and avoid stopping in a callee frame.

However, this frame detection doesn't always handle unexpected changes to the stack pointer, and it would appear that in this case, GDB is getting very confused about what's going on.

Switching to `stepi` should solve these problems.  This command is much more basic, it does no frame detection, or line table analysis, it just asks the inferior to perform a single instruction step.

The `nexti` is a bit of a mix.  It does generally just single step, but it also does use frame analysis to work out when it has entered a callee function.  If the stack pointer is adjusted then I suspect you might still see issues with `nexti`.

In general the `step` and `next` commands should work just fine, its only when you start doing things like adjusting the stack-pointer, or performing a context switch, that GDB will get confused and your are better switching to `stepi`.